# Graceful fail in linux kerenl init_module

Tags: c, linux, kernel, kernel-module

I am working on a kernel module, and I would like to do some checks before loading the module. However, I cannot gracefully prevent module from loading if some checks fail. If module_init function returns a non zero value this causes kernel to crush on my system.

How can I stop module initialization without crushing the kernel? For example just to print an error message etc.

```
static int timer_init(void){
    ...
    if (OK)
       return 0;
    else:
       return -EINVAL;
 }
 static void timer_exit(void) {
 ....
 }
 module_init(timer_init);
 module_exit(timer_exit);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do not quite undestand the problem. Returning negative value from `module_init` function means (for outer world) that module loading fails. If this crushes your system, then **the damage has already been done**, either with previous code of `module_init` or by other kernel component. In the latter case, this is not your problem, and you needn't to do anything with this. If the crush is caused by you init function, you should fix its code.